# function pointer assignment and call in c++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I know when we use the name of a function as a value, the function is automatically converted to a pointer.
look at following code:

```
int print(int a)
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int (*p)(int) = print;
    int (*q)(int) = &print;

    cout << p(8) << endl;
    cout << (*p)(8) << endl;
}
```

why are `int (*p)(int) = print;` , **print** is a pointer, and `int (*p)(int) = &print;`, **&print** is an address to a pointer, equivalent?

On the other hand, when we use a pointer to a function to call the function, why are `p(8)` and `(*p)(8)` equivalent?

Comment: I guess it is just for convenience, that you dont have to explicitly dereference function pointers when using them to call the function. If you use `typedefs` you can work with function pointer without using any `*` which imho is quite nice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does dereferencing of a function pointer happen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen)

Comment: @SimonKraemer thank you. But the link only explain the dereference, my question also include the assignment of function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` is a function, but it is implicitly convertible to a function pointer type. Quoted from [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast):

> **Function to pointer**
>   An lvalue of function type T can be implicitly
>   converted to a prvalue pointer to that function. This does not apply
>   to non-static member functions because lvalues that refer to
>   non-static member functions do not exist.

So, in your case:

```
int (*p)(int) = print; // Conversion happens.
int (*q)(int) = &print; // Conversion does not happen.
```

Implicit conversion kicks in automatically when it is needed to make the program compile, and is not applied otherwise.

With respect to function calling, it is about the built-in function call operator `()`. According to [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other), the built-in function call operator is applicable to both an lvalue expression that refers to a function and a pointer to function. In your case:

```
p(8); // The function call operator is applied to a pointer to function.
(*p)(8); // The function call operator is applied to an lvalue reference to function.
```

For your reference (emphasis mine):

> **Built-in function call operator**
>   A function call expression, such as E(A1, A2, A3), consists of an
>   expression that names the function, E, followed by a possibly empty
>   list of expressions A1, A2, A3, ..., in parentheses. The expression
>   that names the function can be
>
> a) **lvalue expression that refers to a function**
>   b) **pointer to function**
>   ...

Answer (score 3):

`print` is **not** a pointer. Its type is `int(int)`, not `int(*)(int)`. This distinction is especially important in type deduction

```
auto& f = print;   //type of f is int(&)(int), not int(*(&))(int)
template<typename Func>
foo(Func& f);
foo(print);  //Func is deduced to be int(int), not int(*)(int)
```

Analogous to arrays, you cannot copy a function "by value", but you can pass around its address. For example,

```
int arr[4];     //the type of arr is int[4], not int*
int *a = arr;   //automatic array-to-pointer decay
int (*a)[4] = &arr;  //type match 
int (*p)(int) = print;  //automatic function-to-pointer decay
int (*p)(int) = &print; //type match
```

Now when you call `print` through `p`,

```
p(8)     //automatic dereferencing of p
(*p)(8)  //manual dereferencing of p
```

Comment: your answer make some sense. but in the book **c++  primer 5th edition** and many other website tutorial said using function name as rvalue will convert it to a pointer. So I don't know whether your answer is a special condition for function pointer assignment.

Comment: @sydridgm They are correct. And they are referring to the function-to-pointer decay in my answer.