# Calling a function through a function pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers

I don't know how right to call function through pointer.

For example i have this pointer: `int (*ptr)() = a_function;`

To call a function i must write something like this `ptr()` or `(*ptr)()`

What is the difference between these calls? If i write `printf("%p - %p", ptr, *ptr)` I will get an address in the both cases

Comment: The correct answer is `(***ptr)()` if you're a three-star programmer, or `(*****ptr)()` if you're really good. Also, you should have said `(***printf)("%p - %p", ptr, *ptr)`.

Comment: hahaha nice joke, but i want to get the answer

Comment: There is no difference in behaviour or meaning.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen) might be helpful.

Comment: Note: The `%p` conversion type specifier requires a `void *`, which is a object pointer. Functions are not object in C, thus your code invokes undefined behaviour. Many architectures allow to cast a function pointer to `void *`, but you have to do this like for any other pointer explicitly (this is actually a rare occasion you have to cast to `void *`.

Comment: Doing `ptr` gives you the function pointer's value. Doing `ptr()` calls the function the function pointer points to. Mind the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Either works.

This is because when you use a function in an expression, it immediately decays to a pointer - unless it's the operand of `&`, in which case you get a pointer to the function anyway.

So when you write something like `printf("hi")`, you have the function call operator `()` with two operands: `printf`, and an argument list consisting of one value, `"hi"`.

`printf` is a function and it's not the operand of `&`, so what the function call operator `()` actually gets is a function *pointer*. That's why `ptr()` works in your example: Function calls are defined to work with function pointers anyway.

So what about `(*ptr)()`? Well, `ptr` is a function pointer and you can dereference it to get the function ... which immediately decays back to a pointer, so it can be used with `()` to call it.

The same thing applies to `printf` (or any other function). `(*printf)()` is valid for almost the same reason: `printf` decays to a function pointer, which gets dereferenced by `*` to a function, which immediately decays to a pointer again.

Answer (score 0):

A value of function type *decays* to a value of type pointer-to-function in many contexts, similar to how values of array type decay to pointers to the first element of the array.

A function call expression is the postfix expression `E(...)`, where `E` is an expression of either function or pointer-to-function type. This means that a variety of call syntaxes are valid, and all mean the same thing:

```
void f(void);
void (*p)(void) = &f;

f();        // "f" is an expression of function type
p();        // "p" is an expression of pointer-to-function type

(*p)();     // *p is a function
(*f)();     // "f" decays to a pointer, "*f" dereferences that pointer
(****f)();  // like above, but continue decay and deref
(****p)();  // ditto
(**&f)();   // why not
```

Incidentally, one of the contexts in which no decay occurs is as the operand of the address-of operator: So in `&f`, `f` does not decay, but denotes the actual function, whose address is taken. Alternatively, when you write `p = f;`, you use the implicit decay of `f` to `&f`.

Answer (score 0):

C has some magic built-in involving the equivalence of pointers and functions, and the equivalence of pointers and arrays. For that reason, you can sometimes "get away" with not spelling out the full dereference of a pointer when it points to an array or a function.

*However,* I'd like to point out (ahem, see what I did there?) that one of the design goals of C type declarations is that the *declaration* of an object and the *use* of that object are the same.

For example:

```
int   *p;   // p is a pointer to int
```

Now, how do I get an `int`?

```
int y =    /* wait for it ... */   *p;
```

Similarly,

```
float *****p[2];

float y =   *****p[0]; // or [1]
```

So, if you have this declaration:

```
 int (*ptr)() = a_function;
```

Then let's ask the question, "How can you get an int?" Which is to say, how can you invoke the pointer-to-function-taking-no-args-returning-int? The answer is to replicate what you have already declared:

```
 int y = (*ptr)();
```

Yes, you could say "ptr is a pointer, and there is a magic equivalence between functions and pointer-to-functions, to `p()` will work". But don't. Because right now, you aren't confident enough to do that. So just trust that for whatever C declaration, if you want to get the type on the very left, all you need to do is use the `*`'s and `[]`'s and `()`'s on the right, and you'll get there.