# Question related to std::function<>. How is this working?

Tags: c++

Why and how this piece of code is working? The compiler gives no errors or warnings.

```
int sum(int a,int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    std::function<int (int,int)> pa = *****sum;
    std::cout << pa(10,12) << std::endl;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Should have mentioned that too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen ?

Comment: @Asesh it is gcc

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It seems to be a duplicate. This problem is not at all related to `std::function` and the core of the problem is the same.